# Получение информации с html страницы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Есть страница, с таблицей из дивов, куда добавляются ордера пользователей из БД, мне нужно эти ордера экспортировать в csv таблицу, как это можно сделать? Читал, что можно как-то информацию вытащить в файл на сервере и после его уже скачивать, но не совсем понимаю как это сделать.

```
<?php   
session_start();
include_once('db.php');
if(isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
    $sesion_id=$_SESSION['userid'];
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `user` where id=$sesion_id");
    $row = $result->fetch_assoc(); 
    $result2 = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `user_prefs` where id=$sesion_id");
    $user_prefs_row = $result2->fetch_assoc();
    $validsql=$mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `wallets` WHERE id='".$sesion_id."'");
    $valid_row = $validsql->fetch_assoc();
}
else{
    header("");
    exit;
}
if(isset( $_POST['btnexp'] ) )
{
    $check = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM `trade_history`  where $sesion_id=ID_mycode.phpprod");
    $results = array();
    while ($row = $check->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $results[] = $row['Val'] . ',' . $row['Prod'];
    }
    $content = join($results, "\n"); 
    $result->free();
    header("Content-Type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=myfilename.csv");
    echo $content;
}
?>
```

Comment: Есть готовый код переноса таблиц в csv: https://odoepner.wordpress.com/2012/04/09/export-to-html-table-as-csv-file-using-jquery/ на js/jq.

Answer (score 0):

Вы в правильном направлении читали. Вы должны написать сценарий на сервере (это будет PHP, Java, Ruby или любой другой серверный язык) который будет выбирать нужные данные из БД, формировать ответ(содержимое файла) и возвращать его на ваш запрос, установив нужные заголовки

```
"Content-Disposition": "attachment;filename=myfilename.csv"
"Content-Type": "text/csv"
```

Более точно как это сделать можно сказать только зная что вы используете на сервере

Пример для PHP (можно посмотреть на [phpfiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/))

```
<?php

/**
 * Mysqli initial code
 * 
 * Export to CSV example
 * 
 * @package         PhpFiddle
 * @link            http://phpfiddle.org
 * @since           2012
*/

require_once "dBug!.php";

require "util/public_db_info.php";

$short_connect = new mysqli($host_name, $user_name, $pass_word,   $database_name, $port);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM books";   

$result = $short_connect->query($sql);

if (($result) && ($result->num_rows > 0))
{
    $results = array();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
    {
        $results[] = $row['id'] . ',' . $row['title'];
    }

    $content = join($results, "\n"); 

    $result->free();

    header("Content-Type: text/csv");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=myfilename.csv");
    echo $content;
}

$short_connect->close();


?>
```

Comment: вы имеете в виду какие языки я использую?

Comment: Да. На чём написан ваш вэб-сервер

Comment: я использую php и js

Comment: Добавил пример сценария для PHP

Comment: проблема с хедерами, они у меня прописаны в начале файла и мне выдает ошибку Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by

Comment: перенес скрипт в начало файла и поставил выполнение по нажатию по кнопке, но почему-то при загрузке страницы он скачивает файл автоматически, плюс, он после нужной мне информации в таблицу записывает весь html код страницы

Comment: Добавил в вопрос начало файла.

Comment: "Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by" вы получаете потому что где-то перед вызовом header() уже что-то вывели в выходной поток(echo, printf, var_dump и т.п.)

Если файл скачивается при первом входе, то значит условие if(isset( $_POST['btnexp'] ) ) выполняется. Запускайте отладку и смотрите что у вас в переменых.

Comment: А то что в файл попадает весь html код страницы?

Comment: до сих пор не могу понять, почему в файл попадает весь код страницы

Comment: Я же написал: В файл попадает всё, что выводит скрипт. Поэтому это должен быть отдельный запрос.

Comment: т.е этот кусок кода надо поместить в другой php файл?